# jMeter data reporting

Tags: graph, report, jmeter

I have a jMeter test plan with one thread group and a few HTTPRequests inside that thread group. I run the test and now need to visualize the results (ideally, on one graph) for each of the HTTPRequests - avg timing, response size and so on.

Can't figure how do get this with standard listeners - I guess I'm just being silly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standard JMeter listeners are quite simple for nice reporting. Your best choice would be http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/wiki/CompositeGraph with other graphs from that bundle as data sources.